# inline R code within a markdown document with variable names with backticks

Tags: r, r-markdown

I need to do some calculations in within the text of my markdown document like this:

`` `r df1 %>% arrange(`% mujeres candidatas`) %>% mutate(id=row_number()) %>% filter(Depto==depto_may) %>% pull(id)` ``
However, given that the variable name has backticks inside a backtick of the inline code, it does not work. How can I do it?

Comment: before `arrange` use something like `rename(perc_mujeres = "% mujeres candidatas")` and then `arrange(perc_mujeres)`